# vue.js root instance error

Tags: asp.net, vue.js

I have a json:{"IsActive":false}
and I have a code below:

```
new Vue({
el: '#viewport',
data: {

test_data: []
},

mounted: function () {
this.fetchTestData();
},
methods: {
fetchTestData: function () {
    $.get(test.json, function (data) {

        this.test_data = data;
        alert(this.test_data.isActive);
    });

}
}
});
```

I can get the false in alert of isActive, but in the browser it shows me :

> [Vue warn]: Error when rendering root instance:

Any idea  why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be two things problematic in your code:

1. scope of `this` got changed inside `$.get`, due to which it is not assigning to the Vue instance variable.
2. File Name `test.json` has to be in quotes.

You have to make following changes:

```
methods: {
fetchTestData: function () {
    var that = this
    $.get("test.json", function (data) {
        that.test_data = data;
        alert(this.test_data.isActive);
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry,how about using, jquery ajax?
        fetchTestData: function () {
            var that = this;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: apiURL,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    that.test_data = JSON.parse(data.d);
                 alert(this.test_data.isActive);
                }
            });
        },

it also show same error

Comment: @Winston you probable have to write file name in quotes: "test.json"

Comment: thanks,saurabh, but now have "[Vue warn]: Property or method "isActive" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in root instance)"  any idea?

Comment: @Winston Can you add your HTML also in the question. try to create a jsfiddle with it, which will help.

Comment: Also as par guidelines, you can close this question, and ask new question with the new error.